# Plotting Distances of Points in JfreeChart

Tags: jfreechart

I need help in Plotting the Distance of points on Scatter Plot and My Array consist of values whose distances are needed to be calculated.

```
 
A1-(0.3883,0.4197)        
A2-(0.3960,0.3836)        
A3-(0.4065,0.4032)
```

The Distance between A1,A2 is 0.0369 and the distance between A1,A3 is 0.0245 and similarly the Distance between A2,A3 is 0.0221.

My question is how to Plot this Distances(0.0369 of(A1,A2),0.0245 of(A1,A3)..) of that paired values on a Scatter Plot(JfreeChart)?. Please give me Some suggestions on how to a approach this Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data model is a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29), I'd look at [`JGraph`](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html), which has better support for labeled [edges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29).

In [`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/), you could add an item label or tool tip generator to the `XYLineAndShapeRenderer`. The generator would have to query your data model for the relevant [edge value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29). You could arrange for your data model to implement `TableModel` and use a `JTable` as an ancillary display, as shown in [CrosshairDemo1 & 2](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/devguide.html).